# Why does this code only return 'Greetings!' regardless of input?

Tags: python

I'm working through some practice questions in the book "Automate the Boring Stuff," and I'm struggling to understand why the code below only produces 'Greetings!' as output.

```
print('What does spam equal? Hint: Try a number between 1 and 3')
spam = input()
if spam == 1:
    print('Hello')
elif spam == 2:
    print('Howdy')
else:
    print('Greetings!')
```

Comment: because you are taking input as string and condition is based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does because what you have given as input is stored as string in `spam` . And when you are using if else statements then it is comparing with integers, but your actual value is a string, therefore it always turns out to be in the final else statement printing `Greetings!`

So use `spam=int(input())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `input()` returns a string, which is never equal to an integer.
Try

```
spam = int(input())
```

instead. This will of course throw a `ValueError` if the input is not an integer.